# cAdvisor Custome "/metrics" path

Tags: prometheus, cadvisor

Today I played a little bit with `cAdvisor` to monitor all my microservices in my docker containers. All those microservices are providing tons of metrics using prometheus. The prometheus path for every microservice is

```
/management/prometheus
```

cAdvisor is gathering all metrics which are accessible under `/metrics` and for now I could not find any possibility to configure that path. I want cAdvisor to pull all metrics from `/management/promehteus`. Is it somehow possible to configure cAdvisor to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to do this would be to have Prometheus scrape each of the microservices directly, rather than going via something like cAdvisor.

If you were using Consul or Kubernetes for example, your Prometheus could use their respective types of service discovery to find all the services you need to monitor.

Comment: Actually we do scrape each of the microservices directly but for that we have to manually add all services to prometheus and configure them. We want to have something which works automatically so that when we start a microservice prometheus automatically starts monitoring the new service. We thought we could use cAdvisor for that. But yes, we are also using Consul and later we will also use Kubernetes.